# Keeping variable value in jsp 1, after changing to jsp 2 and comming back to jsp1

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have two pages one is step1.jsp, here the user can input its Function, for example DNF and KNF. The user can select gates or multiplexer, with which the function will be simulated in step2.jsp. Now if  the user clicks on "next"-button, he is forwarded to step2.jsp (using Struts2 technologie) where the function is simulated (with gates or multiplexer depending on his choice).

What I want to realize: Throw "back"-button in step2.jsp, when the user clicks on this button, he will be forwarded to step1.jsp and can select "multiplexer" or "gates" again. How to keep the functions, the user has entered in step1, sothat thy can be used again, even after changing to step2.jsp an back to step1.jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some thing like

```
<s:url value="step1.action" var="backURL">
   <s:param name="selectedFunction" value="name_of_the_function" />   
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{backURL}">Back</s:a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want a possibility to keep the functions in step1.jsp before changing to step2.jsp, becasue the function is not availabe in step2.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Make the link include the function to pre-select:

```
<a href="step1.action?function=the_function_you_want_to_preselect>">Back</a>
```

Comment: The problem is, the selected functions are not availabe in step2.jsp. Could  localStorage help for two pages?

Comment: How can step2 simulate a function chosen at step1, and not know the function?

Comment: OK befor changing to step2, the action "in struts2" calls some parser, the function is parsed and simulation informations are preduced and sent to step2.jsp.

Comment: So what? The function is still there in the request parameters. It should also be there in your Struts 2 form. Just because the action has used the function doesn't mean it has disappeared from the request parameters. And even if it had, your action could store it in some request attribute.